# Percent of correct answers program challenge

Tags: c++, percentage

I'm having trouble with the output of my program, the txt files show that the student got 3 answers wrong, but it keeps giving me 0% for percent of correct answers.

The challenge I was given is:

> "One of your professors has asked you to write a program to grade her ﬁnal exams,
>   which consist of only 20 multiple-choice questions. Each question has one of four possible answers: A, B, C, or D. The ﬁle CorrectAnswers.txt contains the correct answers for
>   all of the questions, with each answer written on a separate line. The ﬁrst line contains
>   the answer to the ﬁrst question, the second line contains the answer to the second question, and so forth. 
>   Write a program that reads the contents of the CorrectAnswers.txt ﬁle into a char
>   array, and then reads the contents of another ﬁle, containing a student’s answers, into
>   a second char array.
>
> The program should determine the number of questions that the student
>   missed, and then display the following:
>
> • A list of the questions missed by the student, showing the correct answer and the
>   incorrect answer provided by the student for each missed question
>
> • The total number of questions missed
>
> • The percentage of questions answered correctly. This can be calculated as
>   Correctly Answered Questions  ÷ Total Number of Questions
>
> • If the percentage of correctly answered questions is 70% or greater, the program
>   should indicate that the student passed the exam. Otherwise, it should indicate
>   that the student failed the exam.

This is the code I have so far, thanks in advance for any suggestions!

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <fstream>
#include <string> 
using namespace std;

int main()
{
const int size=20;
static int count=0;
string correctAnswers[size];
string studentAnswers[size];
ifstream inFileC;

inFileC.open("c:/Users/levi and kristin/Desktop/CorrectAnswers.txt");

if (inFileC)
{
for (int i=0;i<20;i++)
{
    inFileC>>correctAnswers[i];
}
}
else
{
    cout<<"Unable to open \"CorrectAnswers.txt\""<<endl;
    cout<<"Please check file location and try again."<<endl<<endl;
}
inFileC.close();

ifstream inFileS;
inFileS.open("c:/Users/levi and kristin/Desktop/StudentAnswers.txt");

if (inFileS)
{
for (int t=0;t<20;t++)
{
    inFileS>>studentAnswers[t];
}
}
else
{
    cout<<"Unable to open \"StudentAnswers.txt\""<<endl;
    cout<<"Please check file location and try again."<<endl<<endl;
}
inFileS.close();

for (int k=0;k<20;k++)
{
    if (correctAnswers[k]!=studentAnswers[k])
    {
        cout<<endl<<"Correct Answer: "<<correctAnswers[k];
        cout<<endl<<"Student Answer: "<<studentAnswers[k]<<endl;
        count++;
    }
}
int percent=((20-count)/20)*100;

cout<<endl<<"Number of missed questions: "<<count;
cout<<endl<<"Percent of correctly answered questions: "<<percent<<"%";

if (percent>=70)
{
    cout<<endl<<endl<<"********"<<endl<<"**Pass**"<<endl<<"********"<<endl<<endl;
}
else
{
    cout<<endl<<endl<<"********"<<endl<<"**Fail**"<<endl<<"********"<<endl<<endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: TL;DR.  Sounds like an integer division issues.  Integer division yields no remainders or fractional quantities.  Convert to floating point before you divide.

Comment: Are you allowed to use floating point numbers?

Comment: yes I am, I just didn't realize that I had to convert it as everyone just informed me. Thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integer division will yield 0 for everything but a perfect score. Use floating-point division instead:

```
int percent = ((double)(20-count) / 20) * 100;
```

Note that `(double)(20-count)` casts the value `(20-count)` into a double-precision floating-point number. Once the whole expression has been evaluated, it gets coerced back to an integer because you're assigning the value to an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Integer divide always rounds towards zero, so `(20 - count)/20` will be zero if count is greater than 0.

Answer (score 0):

Do not need floating point, this will do the trick:

```
int percent = 5 * ( 20 - count );
```